# Laravel collection is empty after using map

Tags: laravel

This works, all posts are dumped with the `votes` property set correctly (if it's `null` then it's updated to have the value `0`):

```php
$posts = Post::all();

foreach($posts as $post) {
  $post->priority = $post->priority ?? 0;
}

dd($posts);
```

But if I do this I get an empty collection back:

```php
$posts = Post::all();

$posts = $posts->map(function ($post) {
    $post->priority = $post->priority ?? 0;
});

dd($posts);
```

From the docs it says that `map` returns a new collection instance and that if you want to modify the existing collection you should use `transform`, but that produces the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return after modifying data inside map

```
$posts = Post::all();

$posts = $posts->map(function ($post) {

    $post->priority = $post->priority ?? 0;

    return $post;
});

dd($posts);
```

As per doc

> The map method iterates through the collection and passes each value
> to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and
> return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items:

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map